# Parse UTC date string and convert to different format

Tags: date, go

Go newcomer here.

I have a date string `2018-06-07T16:16:57Z` and I want to convert it to something like this `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm`.

This seems to be a frequently asked question, but I can't seem to find any previous questions that work for me.

I'm reading in a time field and trying to convert like this

```
time := row["Date & Time"]
fmt.Println(time)
t, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 UTC", time)
fmt.Println(t)
```

But I think the issue is that I don't have a correct format string. I've tried a few resources to no success.

When I print `t` as is, I get `0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC` as a result, which is obviously incorrect.

What I'd like to do is convert the time I'm reading in like this

`newTime := currentDate.Format("01/02/2006 hh:mm")`

Comment: If the date string has no spaces, make sure that the format string has no spaces too. Something like `time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05Z", time)` may be?

Comment: You're not checking the error returned from `time.Parse`. If you did you would find out that both of its arguments' formats must match. This `"2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 UTC"` does not match `"2018-06-07T16:16:57Z"` in format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues.

First, you should not name the variable `time` as that is the name of a built-in package. I suppose you knew that and this is just a copy paste error.

Next, the string you pass to [`time.Parse()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse) is a format string that should describe the format of the time string from your database. You already know what the format is: `2018-06-07T16:16:57Z`, so just use that replacing the value with [Go's reference time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants).

Here is working variant:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    tm := "2018-06-07T16:16:57Z"
    fmt.Println(tm)
    t, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05Z", tm)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

[Run in playground](https://play.golang.org/p/sgaADEMps_b)

---

What's more the time format database uses is often described as RFC3339, which is also available as the `time.RFC3339` constant in Go.

So using that simplifies your code even further:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    tm := "2018-06-07T16:16:57Z"
    fmt.Println(tm)
    t, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, tm)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

[Run in playground](https://play.golang.org/p/11sWeuJwvp7)

---

And if you prefer, you could also let the database driver convert the time for you by scanning it to a `time.Time` variable.

For example:

```
var tm time.Time
if err = row.Scan(&tm); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Print(tm)
```

Answer (score 2):

As @mkopriva describes the layout should be matched. Understand the layout which is `2006-01-02T15:04:05Z`, go through [Golang spec](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse) for `layout` use to convert the string to date

> Parse parses a formatted string and returns the time value it
>   represents. The layout defines the format by showing how the reference
>   time, defined to be

```
Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006
```

and then use returned time value to `Format` the date according to your requirement.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    layout1 := "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z"
    t, err := time.Parse(layout1, "2018-06-07T16:16:57Z")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(t.Format("01/02/2006 15:04"))
}
```

Check it on  [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/qngcsM0r0Bm)